# How to install Gloobus-preview?

Tags: thirdpartyapps

I'm trying to install [gloobus-preview](https://launchpad.net/gloobus-preview) on Freya 0.3.2 but the ppa:gloobus-dev/gloobus-preview doesn't seem to include trusty, are there alternative ppa recomendations? Is there anything else I could try?

I also asked this on the gloobus-preview launchpage. 
https://answers.launchpad.net/gloobus-preview/+question/294541

Update: After reading askubuntu I was able to install it from ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8, is that a recommended ppa?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about elementary OS

Comment: Webupd8 is fine. Andrei is pretty well trusted. However, you should post this as an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

With reference to [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/01/quick-file-previewer-gloobus-preview.html) article use [webupd8](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8) PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gloobus-preview
```

Comment: After doing these steps I have managed to install it in Elementarty OS Loki, and it works if I type in terminal `gloobus-preview` it opens with a preview of the pwd. How can I assign this command with the space bar when I have a file/directory into Pantheon? Any ideas?